# How to migrate user's password between two AzureAD Tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have two AzureAD Tenants,i want to migrate one's users to anothers.
I thinks i can export users form one tenant by the microsoft Graph api,and import the users to another tenants.But the user's password can't export.
So anyone can make a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to migrate user's password between azure AD tenants have raised a case with MS and **Azure doesn’t deliver  direct migration feature between two tenants**